# In C, on variable value changes when reading characters and integers

Tags: c, string, types, character, primitive-types

I'm learning C and I have a question about a little problem that I had. Bear with me, I'm not going to write a full program just the segment of one for concision.

When writing a program that asks for a character and an integer (to create a triangle with said character and to the integer dimensions) I ran a problem where, once I prompted for the character, the value of an entirely different variable (`int x;`) was changed to 0. I solved the problem and got the program to work, but I don't completely understand why this was happening.

For example:

```
char sym[1];    
int x;
printf("number:/n"); //asking for integer
scanf("%d", &x); //reading and assigning x to the value
printf("symbol:/n"); //asking for the character
scanf("%s", &sym); //reading and assign sym to the character
printf("%d",x); //printing the integer
printf("%s",sym); //printing the character
```

My output for `x` would change to 0 no matter what was read into it. This only occured AFTER reading the character.

When I change `char sym[1]` to `char sym[8]` or so, it doesn't change the value of `x`.

I know this must be some memory allocation thing, but does anyone know the details of why this happens? I know that changing the array size for `sym` makes the difference, but why would that change the value of variable `x`?

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow

Answer (score 2):

You should use `%c`, not `%s`, to read single characters. The `%s` specifier reads **strings**, which are **null-terminated arrays of characters**. Since the *sym* vector has enough space for only one character, the null terminator (a zero) is written one byte after *sym*, which happens to be on *x*

1.Possible initial memory layout:
(Each pair of numbers is one byte.)

```
 00 00 00 00 00
 -- -----------
sym[0]   x
```

2.After `scanf("%d", &x);` reads "7":

```
 00 07 00 00 00
 -- -----------
sym[0]   x
```

3A.If `scanf("%s", &sym);` reads "A":
(65 is the ASCII code for A)

```
 65 00 00 00 00
 -- -----------
sym[0]   x
```

3B.If `scanf("%s", &sym);` reads "AAA":

```
 65 65 65 00 00
 -- -----------
sym[0]   x'
```

Another issue in your code is that you shouldn't use `&` when `scanf`ing strings, since `sym` is already the address you want to save to.

Answer (score 2):

In this code behavior is undefined both in scanf and in printf.

1. Buffer is 1 character long; in c string is a an array of chars with '\0' terminating symbol (which is integer 0). So you need at least 2 chars to read one char as a string.
   In this case you even can't print string, because it prints characters until find first 0.
2. scanf string like %<number>s, that will protect buffer from overflow. Or better use other functions to read strings
3. \n is newline, not /n

   ```
   char sym[2];
   int x;
   printf("number:\n"); //asking for integer
   scanf("%d", &x); //reading and assigning x to the value
   printf("symbol:\n"); //asking for the character
   scanf("%1s", &sym); //reading and assign sym to the character
   printf("%d\n", x); //printing the integer
   printf("%s", sym);
   ```

In your code x is zero, maybe because 0 overflows sym and overwrites x. But on my computer x is not zero, because x is located with some offset.